# Laravel check if user exists

Tags: laravel, validation

i am using Laravel 5.2.45

I am trying to create new user to my application.
Before the user is created, i need to check if there is a user with the same name, surname and birthday.
How can i do it in laravel?

Comment: By doing database queries to see if those values are in your database.  See [query builder docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries). Your question is quite basic and likely to be closed because you have no code showing that you've attempted to do this yourself.

Comment: laravel offers for example 'unique' to check if some data already exists in the database. But i am not looking for one entry. 3 entries have to match to give an error. I know i can make a db query and check if there is already an existing user but thought there is a better way to do it in laravel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

User with the same name, surname, and birthday

```
$duplicate_user = \DB::table('users')
    ->where('name', 'LIKE', $new_name)
    ->where('surname', 'LIKE', $new_surname)
    ->where('birthday', '=', $new_birthday)
    ->first();

if($duplicate_user) {
    return response('This user already exists', 422);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Laravel Validation [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-unique) says

> unique:table,column,except,idColumn

```
Validator::extend('and_unique', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
$result = DB::table($parameters[0])->where(function($query) use ($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
    $query->where($attribute, '=', $value) // where name = value
        ->orWhere($parameters[1]), '=', $value); // where surname = value
        ->orWhere($parameters[2]), '=', $value); // where birthday = value
})->first();

return $result ? false : true;
});

'name' => 'required|and_unique:users,surname,birthday'
```

Comment: This will not work. if one of the name, surname or birthday is taken this will give an error.

Answer (score -1):

```
$siteUser = new SiteUser;

foreach (['birth_date', 'first_name', 'last_name'] as $key) {
$siteUser->$key = $request->$key;
}
```

Comment: Can you add some details to your answer? Why should OP use this code?