# Throw not found error if user not exist in database Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication

I'm using `Auth::attempt($credentials)` to authenticate login data from users.

```
$credentials = [
    'user_name' => $request->user_name,
    'password' => $request->password,
];

if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
    return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
} else {
    return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Invalid credentials!');
}
```

If a user types the wrong password or wrong username, I throw an invalid credentials error. But I want if a user does not exist in the database, I can throw an error that the user does not exist.

My `Auth::attempt($credentials)` returns true or false, so I don't know how to do this. Can you help?

Comment: Throwing a 404 could actually be considered a security flaw, because you're exposing information to potential attackers as to the username of valid accounts. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: This question can be reworded into: "How do I check if a user already exists"
so I recommend looking into: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42416753/laravel-check-if-user-exists

but as @fubar mentioned, a vague "Incorrect username/password" should be enough; there is no need to state "username already taken" unless you are registering.

Comment: I really appreciate all your advice, I finally get the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$user = User::where('user_name',$request->user_name)->first();

if($user) {
  $credentials = [
    'user_name' => $request->user_name,
    'password' => $request->password,
  ];

  if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
    return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
  } else {
    return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Invalid credentials!');
  } 
} else {
  return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Not found!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be an security issue sir as @fubar said, but the simple logic is

1. Find at users table if email is exists.
2. if exists then go to auth attempt like the way you implement already.
3. if not exists throw 404.